# Route map drawing in google maps using coordinate values of location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

> I'm developing a map application in which the users will select the
>   origin and destination points from a list of available points in
>   drop-down. All I want is that the map generated should take the values
>   of latitude and longitude instead of string values as I mentioned in
>   below code. How can I achieve this?

I also wonder if I could draw my custom map with my own routes instead of google generated routes.

Any help is appreciated!

```
 <b>Start: </b>
    <select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    <b>End: </b>
     <select id="end" onchange="calcRoute();">
      <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
      <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
      <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
      <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
      <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
      <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
      <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
      <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
      <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
      <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
      <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
      <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

The JS part is :

```
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: {
                lat: 41.85,
                lng: -87.65
            }
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

    var onChangeHandler = function() {
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    };
    document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    directionsService.route({
        origin: document.getElementById('start').value,
        destination: document.getElementById('end').value,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but it's the solution for android API right? I need some thing for direct web application.

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry. I saw the 'Google maps tag' and thought it was Android by default. My bad. I have deleted that comment.

Comment: This could be a good starting point: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/

Comment: What are the coordinates you want to use?  Where are they coming from? The code in the question contains addresses (and works). Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may use waypoints for this, you will have to put location which is the address of the waypoint. You can have an array of waypoints to add to your route. Please see this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=FR#Waypoints) to know how to use this.